# why join website address and api address in the post angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular8

I find myself deploying an application. I have in production environment variables an address that is from the api where request .. but it is not working because when making the post request the web page address is being added, that is: my web address is *http://172.19.116.98/appcalidad/#/login* and the api address is *http://172.19.116.98/Calidad/public/api/users*. But when I'm making the request to api in the service post I don't know why Angular is joining these two urls *http://172.19.116.98/appcalidad/172.19.116.98/Calidad/public/api/login*. It should be noted that it works well locally. How do I get it to be excluded .. the part highlighted in yellow is the address of the api and the one before it is the web address ..

[image: Error console]
The service login:

[image]

the part highlighted in yellow is the address of the api and the one before it is the web address

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you have not added the protocol to the URL. Add `http://` to the `apiURL` variable and it should work. Not adding this causes the path to become relative to the current URL. Hence the Post Request URL is getting appended to the page URL.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is thinking the URL is relative, not absolute, since `http://` or `https://` protocol is missing.

You should set `apiUrl` to:

```
http://172.19.116.98/Calidad/public/api
```